# Can a client with an ECC certificate and a server with RSA certificate establish a mTLS connection?

Tags: rsa, ecc, authentication, tls

Can a client with an ECC certificate and a server with RSA certificate establish a mTLS connection?
Can they agree on a cipher suite?
Why?

Comment: Yes, yes, and "because cipher suites are about what's implemented and enabled". I recommend you read over the [TLS handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more a matter of practice in security protocols than of cryptography, but: **YES, DEPENDING**.

In older versions of TLS through 1.2 (and before TLS, in SSL3) each possible ciphersuite specifies, among other things, the keyexchange method which controls the 'type' of server certificate to be used, and how -- more exactly, what the algorithm of the key in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo must be, and what must be set in the KeyUsage extension if used. See the table in [RFC5246 section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) in particular the entries for RSA and DHE_RSA/ECDHE_RSA. If the client offers at least one ciphersuite acceptable to the server and using one of these keyexchanges, and for a keyexchange using RSA-signing (DHE_RSA or ECDHE_RSA) in 1.2 either omits signature_algorithms or includes at least one adequate RSA signature, and the server has a suitable RSA privatekey and cert, it can use it.

The *client* certificate, OTOH, is not controlled by the ciphersuite. If used at all, it is controlled by the CertificateRequest message in [section 7.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4) as modified by [RFC4492 section 5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-5.5) and [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-3). If the server requests `ecdsa_sign`, the client can use a signing-capable ECC cert (informally, an ECDSA cert). The server can't request either of the `ecdh_fixed` cert types here, because those keyexchanges would require the server use an ECDH cert which your case doesn't.

[For 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446) the protocol changes but the result is the same. Plain-RSA and static-DH keyexchanges no longer exist, so the server certificate is now used *only* for authentication (signing), and is not linked to the ciphersuite but (only) to the client's signature_algorithms in ClientHello which is now mandatory. Conversely, the client's certificate (if any) is controlled only by signature_algorithms in CertificateRequest (if used). For ECDSA the signature_algorithm values now control the curve as well, which they didn't do in lower versions. It is perfectly fine for the algorithms to be different.

Of course all other requirements must be met: the client must validate the server's cert against the client's truststore at the current time, and for some protocols (like HTTPS) validate its hostname(s); the server must validate the client's cert against the server's truststore at the current time, and optionally check its identity information; the key size(s) and hashes used must be considered strong enough (not RSA-1024, MD5, SHA-1) as must the DHE or ECDHE parameters if used; other extensions like RFC5746, RFC7366, RFC7627, and single or multi OCSP (especially if stapled), must either be agreed or their absence accepted; unacceptable downgrade must not be detected. And probably more I've forgotten.